# Terminating spring boot app after executing liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I would like to build an init container (kubernetes) with spring boot which only runs liquibase. For this I have created 2 profiles.

Init:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
```

Start:

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
```

When I execute the Application in the IDE everything works as expected and the process ends. When I execute the Application in a docker container within kubernetes, I see the output for the startup time and the process stays running. I don't see any shutdown output either.

Anyone have any idea how to finish the process?

**EDIT**

There was a issue on the microsoft key vault starter:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/22170

This dependencies is only added for cloud deployment. After the dependency is added locally, the problem is reproducible in the IDE.

Comment: Is this really about the application or about stopping the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/22170 and update the version of the key vault starter